# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

Tags: php, migration

I am migrating my site from PHP 4 to 5

I keep getting this error on the version 5 server:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   ';' in /var/www/vhosts/****.php on
>   line 1688

I when I check the code its something like this:

```
<?=#something here being commented out?>
```

This worked fine in v4 but now its creating an Error. I really do not understand the error either because there is no `;` in the entire line anywhere?

I can just delete the line but I am wondering why this error is happening in the first place and if there is something else I can do besides hunting down every occurrence of that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
<?=#something here being commented out?>
```

Translates into this:

```
<?php echo /*something here being commented out*/; ?>
```

You just have to fix the syntax I presume.

Comment: Changing it to `<?#=something here being commented out?>` should work

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting that enables `<?` to be shorthand for `<?php` - ensure that is enabled.

Comment: That's 100% correct.

   This directive also affects the shorthand `<?=`, which is identical to `<? echo`. Use of this shortcut requires `short_open_tag` to be on.

Answer (score 0):

unexpected ';' indicates more that it was not expecting the end of a command. In your code, you have a shorthand open tag. You're basically telling it to echo and not passing it an argument when you do:

```
<?= //comment ?>
```

If you shorten this to:

```
<?php //echo 'something'; ?>
```

You would be safe.